# HTTPS connection hangs on TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, https, handshake

I'm connected on the internet using a B525s Huawei router using 4G.

I tried 2 operators in Switzerland:
- sunrise (www.sunrise.ch)
- salt (www.salt.ch)

With 'salt' I have no problems what so ever. However with sunrise for around 2 months some websites are randomly not accessible. The more critical one being cloudflare.

```
curl -v https://www.cloudflare.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.cloudflare.com/
*   Trying 198.41.215.162...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.cloudflare.com (198.41.215.162) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.cloudflare.com:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

The support line of sunrise is of no help. They answer me that they don't support IP ;)

What I tried:

- change the router
- change the MTU (to 1492 on my computers)
- try different IP address using the --resolve option of curl

The only way to succeed to connect was to change of provider (using salt instead of sunrise) but this is not a long term solution for me.

Any idea about what could be the reason of this and how to test it ?

Comment: It looks like it is not getting the final response from the server in the TLS handshake but this might also because the server is not getting the data from the client. SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL could mean various things, for example an explicit reset or also a timeout. Could you do a packet capture to get more details about the problem and provide the pcap or upload it to cloudshark.org? Could also try to set the MTU on your computer even lower, for example to 1300?

Comment: Or the "poor man's capture": `openssl s_client -connect $host:443 -servername $host -debug </dev/null >$logfile`